# Unparseable date: "2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00" in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to convert date: `2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00` into IST format.

Till far I did:

```
    String s = "2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ");
    Date d = formatter.parse(s);


    TimeZone tx=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
    formatter.setTimeZone(tx);
    System.out.println("Formatted date in IST = " + formatter.format(d));
    String istDateFormat = formatter.format(d);
    //Date da=formatter.format(d);
    return istDateFormat;
```

But I am getting error:

```
Unparseable date: "2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"");
```

This is shold work, check the example in the Java Doc. There is `:` in between your TimeZone,

Your pattern suitable for `2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700` format.

Comment: 'X' will only work in Java 7 though. an iso 8601 date is harder to parse with java 6

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.Date & .Calendar & SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

The alternatives, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8)’s new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) solve your problem with less code. No need to bother with formatters and parsing as they both take [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings directly.

Note one big difference: While java.util.Date objects have no time zone (effectively UTC/GMT), in both Joda-Time (DateTime) and java.time (ZonedDateTime) the date-time object knows its own assigned time zone and offset.

## Joda-Time

```
String input = "2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00";
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ); 
DateTime dateTimeIndia = new DateTime( input, timeZone );  // Parse as a -06:00 value, then adjust 11.5 hours to India +05:30 time zone.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ); // For comparison.
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );  
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-02-24T06:54:12.417Z
dateTimeIndia: 2014-02-24T12:24:12.417+05:30
```

## java.time (Java 8)

```
String input = "2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00";
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeIndia = ZonedDateTime.parse( input ).withZoneSameInstant( zoneId );  // Parse as a -06:00 value, then adjust 11.5 hours to India +05:30 time zone.
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUtc = zonedDateTimeIndia.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ); // For comparison.
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zonedDateTimeUtc: " + zonedDateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "zonedDateTimeIndia: " + zonedDateTimeIndia );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-02-24T00:54:12.417-06:00
zonedDateTimeUtc: 2014-02-24T06:54:12.417Z
zonedDateTimeIndia: 2014-02-24T12:24:12.417+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"

Answer (score 0):

You are using [RFC time zone notation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) for your date format.

But your date string is [ISO formatted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)

So it not able to parse your date.

Either do one of the following

- change the formatter to have ISO format (i.e change `ZZZ` to `XXX`)
- Or change you date string like  2014-02-24T00:54:12.417 **-0600**